# How to just read just one value in a json response?

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using the Zephyr api and it's returning me json array containing json objects in something like this...

```
{
"executions": [
    {
        "id": 24,
        "cycleId": 13,
        "cycleName": "CLONE - Audit Test Cycle 2",
        "issueKey": "ZFJ-2",
        "projectKey": "ZFJ",
        "project": "ZFJ",
        "priority": "Major",
        "component": "c1",
        "versionId": 10000,
        "version": "v1",
        "status": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "FAIL",
            "description": "Test was executed and failed.",
            "color": "#CC3300",
            "type": 0
        },
        "executedOn": "18/Oct/13",
        "creationDate": "18/Oct/13",
        "executedBy": "admin",
        "executedByUserName": "admin"
    },
    {...},
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cycleId": 1,
        "cycleName": "Audit Test Cycle",
        "issueKey": "ZFJ-2",
        "projectKey": "ZFJ",
        "project": "ZFJ",
        "priority": "Major",
        "component": "c1",
        "versionId": 10000,
        "version": "v1",
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "PASS",
            "description": "Test was executed and passed successfully.",
            "color": "#75B000",
            "type": 0
        },
        "executedOn": "4/Oct/13",
        "creationDate": "4/Oct/13",
        "executedBy": "admin",
        "executedByUserName": "admin"
    }
]
```

Originally I was using org.json to parse the json array but it seemed very slow to me when I am just parsing about 200 json objects. The only thing I need from each object is the "id", so I was thinking to just parse the document myself by scanning for the "id" in each json object, instead of using org.json to parse the whole json response.

Will this improve my parsing performance instead of using org.json? How can I scan a json response without a parser? I am assuming a json response is still a line of text and the parser is what retrieves the key and value.

Are there better alternatives to what I suggested? A more efficient parser? How is org.json performance compare to other parsers?

Comment: You don't need to write this yourself, it already exists. Look at this for example http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/

Answer (score 1):

Parsing JSON manually is rarely a good idea.

Just go with an established library and there will not be problems. [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) could be a good choice. It shows good performance, and the linked example is easy to follow. You do not even need to create a complicated structure if you only need the ID field (you can safely omit the rest of the fields).